# Bootcamp, Face Time HD camera image - How to "Flip Horizontal"

Tags: bootcamp, windows, camera, facetime

I am using the built in Face Time HD camera (iMac Mid 2011) via Bootcamp on Windows 7. It basically works great, but I need to switch the output image horizontally. The software I am using does not provide that function. There is actually a switch in the driver pop up for "Flip Horizontal" but it is deactivated.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/LSCgM.png]

Is there any way to have this activated? (or are there known third party plugins that could provide the "flipping" function?)